# jQuery append incorrectly displaying float number

Tags: javascript, jquery

its been an hour since i started working on this and i cand find the problem

this is my code inside the loop

```
$.each(data,function(key,game){
    console.log(game.teams_odds[1].game_odds_value_modified);
    var home_odds = parseFloat(game.teams_odds[0].game_odds_value_modified).toFixed(2);
    var away_odds = parseFloat(game.teams_odds[1].game_odds_value_modified).toFixed(2);
    console.log(away_odds);
    $("#oddsTable").append('<tr>' +
                                '<td>' +
                                    '<span class="red">Game ID : '+game.game_id+' </span>' +
                                        '<br>'+game.game_start_time+'<br>' +
                                '</td>' +
                                '<td>' +
                                    '<span class="teamName">'+game.teams_odds[0].team_name_eng+'</span>' +
                                    '<span class="teamName">'+game.teams_odds[1].team_name_eng+'</span>' +
                                '</td>' +
                                '<td>' +
                                    '<span style="display: block">' +
                                        '<a href="{if $isDotNet == 0}/{$kioskUrl}/single-pop/{$dataHolders.team_home_game_details}/bettype/{$betType}/baseball/{else}/pop_bet.php?gdid={$dataHolders.team_home_game_details}{/if}" class="teamOdds{if $dataHolder.blink_it == 1 && $dataHolder.blink_it_game_details_id == $dataHolder.game_details_id_home} blinkMe{/if}" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">' +
                                            +home_odds+
                                        '</a>' +
                                    '</span>' +
                                    '<span style="display: block">' +
                                        '<a href="{if $isDotNet == 0}/{$kioskUrl}/single-pop/{$dataHolders.team_away_game_details}/bettype/{$betType}/baseball/{else}/pop_bet.php?gdid={$dataHolders.team_away_game_details}{/if}" class="teamOdds{if $dataHolder.blink_it == 1 && $dataHolder.blink_it_game_details_id == $dataHolder.game_details_id_away} blinkMe{/if}" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">' +
                                            +away_odds+
                                        '</a>' +
                                    '</span>' +
                                    '<br>'+game.game_start_time+'<br>' +
                                '</td>' +
                           '</tr>'
                           );
});
```

when i try to use `console.log()` and `alert()` to show the values just fine, but when i see my rendered html from using `append` it the number lacks the number zero **zero**

say `1.60`
becomes `1.6`

`console.log(away_odds) //1.60` 
`alert(away_odds) //1.60`

what i want is for it to display `1.60` but it keeps displaying `1.6`

Comment: Try `+ ' away_odds '+` in case its getting interpreted as a number automatically.

Comment: `.append()` itself doesn't do anything to the string you pass other than to turn it into DOM nodes. It seems like you may be  using some sort of templating system. Could that be interfering?

Comment: @Anthony: That would append the literal string `"away_odds"` instead of the value of the variable.

Comment: Don't use .toFixed(2) before itself. Use it only when you are displaying inside the <td>.. check my answer for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've concatenated the previous line already:

```
'<a href="{if $isDotNet == 0} ... style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">' +
    +away_odds+ //                                                    extra + --^
'</a>' +
```

Leading `+` on the second line is actually [Unary Plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29), which converts `away_odds` to a number again. Also `home_odds` will be converted to a number for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

`toFixed(2)` should only be used in the part of the code that outputs it.

In this case,

```
var home_odds = parseFloat(game.teams_odds[0].game_odds_value_modified);
var away_odds = parseFloat(game.teams_odds[1].game_odds_value_modified);
```

And where you are printing the variables use

```
home_odds.toFixed(2)
```

I have tested it and it works fine

Comment: Why would that make a difference? There's nothing wrong with storing the result of `.toFixed(2)` in a variable unless there are going to be other mathematical operations on it.

Comment: Given the code in the question, it wouldn't actually make a difference since the `.toFixed()` will be evaluated before the extra `+` operator that exists as [@Teemu pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646936/jquery-append-incorrectly-displaying-float-number#comment36316741_23647089).

Comment: Basically `var x = 1.6; console.log("foo " + +x.toFixed(2) + " bar"); // "foo 1.6 bar"`. The extra `+` is the actual issue, which in both cases converts the result of `.toFixed(2)` to a number.

Comment: @cookiemonster i ran this code var x = 1.34302; console.log("foo " + +x.toFixed(2) + " bar"); // "foo 1.34 bar" the extra + is really not an issue

Comment: It's an issue when you want trailing `0`s. The numeric conversion truncates unnecessary leading and trailing `0`s since they add no value to the number. So I'm not saying that `.toFixed()` doesn't work. I'm saying that it does work, but then the extra `0`s it provides are being destroyed by the numeric conversion by `+`, which happens after the `.toFixed()` operation.